# How to get referral site URL?

Tags: c#

I have posted my site URL on Facebook. Now I am coming to my site after clicking the link shared on Facebook. I want to capture the Facebook URL from where I am coming to my site. I want to get the referral site URL in my webapplication.

How do I get the referral site URL using C#?

Comment: Also, what technology are we talking about? WebForms? MVC?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

More information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) though I suspect there may be issues getting the referrer from Facebook, since FB connections are generally HTTPS and I'm pretty sure you don't get referrer info from HTTPS connections.

Good luck :)